# How can I make authorized requests to secured API endpoint from cronjobs?

Tags: go, kubernetes, cron, kubernetes-ingress

I have a golang application which has API key authorization via the `JWT token`

I am using Kubernetes. So, this golang app is in a pod.

Now, I want to create another application for cronjobs to hit golang endpoint once a week.

**What I need:**

How to ***do / skip*** the authorization?

**skip**: Ingress is not required here as I can simply call it internally. Can that help this case?

**What I Tried:**

I tried keeping the cronjobs and api in the same application so I can simply call the *service instead of the endpoint*, But that also has a drawback.
I am not able to create replicas as they will also replicate the cronjobs and the same endpoint will be hit `1*no of replicas` times

I want to call "abc.com" endpoint once a week. It requires a token and I cannot simply pass a token.
I hope there is some way around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just have to call them internally without exposing them, it can certainly help.
Provided both Pods (and therefore Deployments) are running under the same Cluster you can use Kubernetes' internal DNS.

K8s automatically creates DNS records for Services you create that can be used for internal communication by following this specific format: `<service-name>.<service-namespace>.svc.cluster.local`

More information from the official docs here: [DNS for Services and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)

If it sounds weird or if it can help understanding the gist of it, try to think of the "endpoint" as a rule you add to your system's hosts file: it boils down to basicly adding a rule where `<service-name>.<service-namespace>.svc.cluster.local` points to your pod's IP address, except it's done automatically

E.g.

- Your golang app is running inside a Pod.
- You created a Service pointing to it, named `go-api` and under the namespace `go-apps`.
- If your cron-job worker is running in a Pod inside the same cluster, you can use `go-api.go-apps.svc.cluster.local[:<port>]` to reach your app without using an Ingress

The authorization is up to you, since you're usually handling it either directly or by using specific frameworks.
You could, for example, add a custom endpoint path inside your app where you make sure that the only accepted clients come from the same, private IP subnet of your cluster, either without a token (not recommended) or with a specific semi-fixed one that you generate and control, so that you would send a request to something like this from your crons: `go-api.go-apps.svc.cluster.local:8080/api/v1/callWithNoAuth`

Comment: Hi Leo, thanks for the answer. I am assuming this will behave as an endpoint go-api.go-apps.svc.cluster.local[:<port>] (though I skip the ingress) 
How do I skip the authorization? It is the go application that does the authorization using mux middleware.

Comment: Edited the answer to complete it with what you asked. Hopefully should be enough, unless you're asking how to circumvent another application's (that you do not control) authorization schemes. This is not the right place for that.

Comment: So, you want my handler/controller to check where the request is coming from? Can you elaborate on "with a specific semi-fixed one that you generate and control" this. In my app, the token has an expiration time so are u saying to create a token with no expiry?

Comment: I don't "want", I'm merely providing an example of how you could do it. As they say, "there are multiple ways to skin a cat", but it depends on the requirements you and your app have to meet. 
A never-expiring fixed token (albeit not recommended).
A token you manually generate and change at regular intervals.
A network filter which admits only "private" IP addresses.
A certificate you exchange.
A "EaaS" framework like this would work [link](https://www.vaultproject.io/use-cases/dynamic-secrets).
Any of the above would work, a combination of the above **could** work.

Answer (score 0):

I am creating a new answer as I feel I have more points to contribute to this.
So, what I eventually did end up doing is creating a middle-ware for internal API calls. Inside this middleware, I authorize the caller in middleware i.e. check whether it is from "`xyz-service:port`".

I found that the need to use a 3rd party authenticator was overkill and using a token in code was riskier.

Since all the services except for the ingress is `ClusterIP`, No one can access it from outside directly.

Thanks to @LeoD's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74520139/20563540). I gained confidence using this method.

P.S. Simply *service-name*:port can suffice
eg: `http://myservice:4000/api`

Comment: Great that you're adding extra helpful information! It's best if you edit your first answer and add that extra info in there, this makes for a single and strong answer. Helpful for people who might google this question in the future :)